# How can I reduce multiple hyphens to a single hyphen for inbound URLs?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, url

How can i make it so if a visitor comes in from google through this old url

`https://www.oceanreef.dk/shop/83-fisk-sundhed/8863-esha-exit---20ml/`

go to:

`https://www.oceanreef.dk/shop/83-fisk-sundhed/8863-esha-exit-20ml/`

the problem is I made a new webshop for the client, and in the old shop he could make severeal hyphens. And now the url has only one ☺️

Can I fix it in htaccess or with a function?

thanks in advance :)

Didnt try anything myself yet

Comment: Yes, you can fix that, but the best solution would be to fix the output (such that your application does not display the "wrong" links anymore). What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask].

Comment: `Didnt try anything myself yet` is a problem on SO. :)

Comment: @NicoHaase, one can't easily fix indexed search results or third-party bookmarks.

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like the following in your **header.php** theme file...

```
  <?php
    if(is_404()) {
        $request = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        $path = $request["path"];
        if(strpos($path,'---')){
            $result = trim(str_replace('---', '-', $path));
            header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
            header('Location: '.$result.'');
        }
    }
?>
```

Place it at the top of the theme file before any other content gets rendered, otherwise the headers already get assigned.

The conditional checks if you are getting a 404 error page (because the old url page does not exist in the new website) and then it reads the path used. It will grab the old url as you shared, replace the extra hyphens with a single one, and then update the headers to take the user to the new location.

Comment: Nice! ☺️ Thanks Bench! ☺️ 

Can you make the code so that it checks if the url has more than one hyphen in a row, because some places there are 2 hyphens, some places 3 and someplaces 5 or even 6 in a row? 